# How to check the private files in IPFS

Tags: file, cryptography, private, ipfs

How to check the file is private or not in IPFS, and also how to provide the Key Contracts to particular file in IPFS.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on IPFS an file is not private all node has access all. if we want use IPFS to share a private content you need install IPFS. after that you need disconnect public cluster : https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-swarm-disconnect

however for the moment (current version ipfs) your node continue share own DHT table with ipfs.io but your ressource is only enable your node.

Comment: It is suggested [in a comment mistakenly posted as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74628324/5211833) that that link is now dead. Can you revisit this please?